# What's the best way to detect a STOP sign using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I am new to OpenCV. I was assigned a task to detect a STOP sign using OpenCV. After doing some research, came to know that it can be possible by building a Haar classifier and feeding it up with positive and negative images. I was wondering, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Please read [ask]. You question now is far too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a simple SURF or SIFT is good enought... Have you tryed?